# Receiving multiple outbound messages for single event

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

We have set up outbound messaging that is triggered when new accounts are created. It seems that SalesForce is sending us 5 instances of the outbound SOAP message with identical content.

Have others seen this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the OM monitoring log, sounds like the app might not be seeing your ACK, and is retrying the delivery.